# highlighting and saving multiple words in a single string using python

Tags: python, html, replace, highlight, docx

I'm pretty new to programming and I've been having a problem: I have a `txt` file with a long (30,000+ chars) single string made of 4 letters (a DNA sequence) and I need to search that file for certain repeats (for example `'TTAGGG'`), highlight them and save as a simple readable file. obviously I can't save it as a `txt` file because there is no highlight option.

I tried `html` as well as `docx` but every search I try removes the previous highlights.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, am I correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162036/is-there-a-way-to-write-formatted-text-from-python

Answer (score 0):

Open it in MS-Word, and do following Find-and-replace:

[image]

Comment: sorry i wasnt clear.. i need to do it using python.
thanks for the answers anyways, i figured something out